Why would governments and scientific institutions not kidnap powerful superhumans
Setup/Question
In most superhero settings the government and other institutions do not kidnap super humans. This seems rather odd as if super humans existed in real life then they would probably get kidnapped and sent to work in the military. Clearly there is some reason preventing the government or other institutions from kidnapping super-powered individuals. So what is a plausible reason for powerful super humans to not get kidnapped by the government and other institutions?
Details

The government has the means to kidnap the super humans.
The identity of the superhuman is widely known
Lets say that the superhuman is a powerful telekinetic.


I'm having trouble not seeing this as story-based - the motivations and actions of individuals being up to the author. Perhaps you can: 1) Specify the superpowers concerned. 2) The Capabilities of the government. - Even then, it goes to motivation unless you can specifically exclude that possibility somehow. (A possible solution is the hero is bound by a vow to self-destruct rather than be captured and the resultant explosion would destroy half the planet.)

??? Those superhumans are still humans, citizens of their own countries. They have rights. May some disreputable governments are reputed abduct persons of interest. Civilized governments try to avoid doing that; rule of law and so on. This is generally considered a Bad Thing to do and runs the risk of generating Very Bad Publicity.

Questions about the motivations and decions of organizations or individuals within your world are not permitted on this site. Human motivation is too complex for questions about it to work in our structured Q&A format.

"if super humans existed in real life then they would probably get kidnapped and sent to work in the military" so...you believe that an uncooperative human with superpowers should be placed in the military and they won't do anything to sabotage it?!

@sphennings He did not specifically say that he's looking for motivations or choices.  This question can be answered by other things having nothing to do with individual choices.  If he did not ask for it, then it is the onus of those answering not to give it.

VTC:Too Story-Based. When you remove all of the story-independent reasons (like the government not having the physical power necessary to take and hold the super) all that's left are story-based reasons (e.g., the law grants them their freedom, they're popular with the people, etc.). All story-based reasons have equal value, which is prohibited in the [help/dont-ask]. Per the [help/on-topic], we do not help people write their stories.

Opps, I missed the part that the government must have the means to do it.  Yeah, VtC.

Better question why would they try to, what do you think they will get out of super power weilders taken against their will, they certainly can't use them in combat. Can you think of any reason that  outweights the bad publicity of abducting their own citizens?

Fictitious democratic governments s/times kidnap their own super-powerful citizens, as in René Barjavel's Le grand Secret (translated as "The immortals"). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Immortals_(Barjavel_novel)

I'm having trouble why people think this is story-based? If we have two countries with specific backgrounds we expect them to behave in specific ways. Almost all of them would have some reaction should superhumans come into existence. And he's asking why countries might opt not to kidnap them to attempt to control them, which we know for certain some governments would do.

Working together
If we strip the 'superhuman' from the equation, we can see more clearly why not. Currently there are amazing people in the world. People with absolute stellar IQ that can change the world. From 'attacks' like hacking, or simply building new IT or hardware solutions. These people are invaluable.
Are they locked up? Absolutely not. You offer them a job. Well paid so they are happy. Offer a good social environment with it, and they have little to no reason to harm you. Even better, they might go that extra mile for their employers. Whether to showboat or as appreciation does not really matter. There have been plenty of people who did criminal things and have later been employed for prevention or strengthening whatever was impacted and more.
Translate this to superpowered people. Would you want to give them a nice, cozy environment,  indoctrinate them a bit so they do not realise the people on the other side also just want a partner and to afford a house. Have the superpowered people work for you. Or do you want to kidnap them and put them under harsh conditions, which is most likely not a way for them to perform at their best? Would you risk their wrath? If movies are anything to go by, that is an origin story where death and destruction are waiting.
There is also a monetary incentive not to kidnap someone. You might require a special facility for containment, 24/7 surveillance from technology and humans, gear, and even the restaurant will cost you a lot of money. You can put that to pay the superpowered human. You'll obviously still want to invest in some checks and balances, but the cost of containing the (super)human is much higher than a normal (optional) research facility. Paying a million or ten a year to the superhuman is potentially much cheaper and cost effective.
If you truly want to get the best, you make them comfortable. Not only do they not want to leave for the monetary and social benefits you offer them. The social network also prevents the shift to more radical thoughts, dampening ideas of going somewhere else or similar. If push really comes to shove, you now have their best friends, their partners and their kids right there. They are imprisoned by their life. Just like most people won't just up and leave.
There is absolutely no reason to kidnap a superpowered human, unless they would otherwise fall under the influence of another. And even then you try to embed them in your social system.

You have every reason to incarcerate - I mean kidnap - a super villain. I'm beginning to wonder if the OP needs to seriously clarify their question. We're all treating "kidnap" like the western democracy crime and not criminal incarceration or fascist/nationalist kidnapping of people who were deemed a threat to the status-quo (Nazis... Communists... lots of examples of governmental kidnapping out there).

@JBH if crimes are committed then it is a different case. Just like with normal highly skilled people you act at that point. Then the definition is indeed not kidnapping, which avoids the whole issue. Not to mention that just in real life these people are at times employed afterwards of their own volition.

I wonder if CC was trying to be funny. The military part reads like CC just thew it in, like the issue hadn't been thought through. But when you remove the emotion and the most common purpose for the word, kidnapping is just compelled custody, no different from incarceration or a draft. (It's like arguing the consequences of murder, execution, and assasination is somehow different because of the word that was used.)  Governments compell custody for all kinds of reasons. So... given that a government can compel custody of a super... why wouldn't it? (In a non-storybuilding way).

Government do not kidnap their citizens to make work for them.
Look at the army: worldwide there are 3 options for having people enlisted.

professional army: people voluntarily enlist for service.
mass army: people are mandated by law to serve in the army.
"sentenced" army: people who are serving time are given the possibility to serve in the army as an alternative.

None of the above is a kidnapping.
The only case where a government kidnaps people is when they belong to other countries and cannot be subjected to any of the above points (see North Korea with the kidnapping of Japanese citizen to train their spies).
But there is a difference in the effort needed between kidnapping a defenseless bystander and kidnapping a superhero.

How does this answer the question? Why would the government choose not to "kidnap" (let's say "incarcerate") a super when it has the ability to do so? (And you might be thinking too much about a traditional western democracy and not something a bit more tyrannical like fascist/Nazi Germany or communist Russia/China where the government kidnapped anybody it felt threatened the status-quo.)

The superhuman is too super human to be drafted!
I'm not sure I agree with your assumption that the government would kidnap a superhuman and force him to work in the military. Any superhuman powers he has, he could use to resist capture and escape. So whatever extra value he gives to the military would not be worth the trouble of keeping him against his will in the first place.
e.g. a telekinetic in a battle - yeah sure he may have an advantage over a mundane soldier but in the grand scheme of things - i.e. army vs army + a telekinetic - he's not going to make a huge difference. He'll have to have guards constantly watching him right from training and all the way through his entire tour of service, to make sure he doesn't turn his powers on his captors, or use his telekinesis to help the enemy, given he probably now hates the government - and those guards will have to be specifically trained at guarding superhumans! Would it be worth it?
The more powerful he is, the more of an advantage he gives, but also the more resources it takes to keep an eye on him.
Maybe a telekineticist would have more value in covert ops or as an assassin - but this means leaving him off on his own, thereby giving him even more opportunity to escape. (In any case, you say he's widely known so that's not going to work, and it's also going to make him a target if he's in the regular military)
It's far more likely that the government would hire him and pay him well for his trouble as Troxidane says.

Tour of service?  For life!  Why would he give up a grudge because he's been discharged?

Is this a Frame Challenge?

@JBH - Maybe, but the question was "Why wouldn't they" and... well, here's why!

Per the [help/on-topic], If ... you aren’t sure what a character (be it an individual or organization) should do, that is out of scope for the site. and per [answer], Answer well-asked questions. If this isn't a frame challenge, then you shouldn't have answered the question.

Little Karen
The proponents of the Super Draft Law argued with two narratives. One was a clear-eyed, clean-cut young man who cheerfully reported to the Super Registration Board and then did his superhuman best to get selected as a Supercop, Supersoldier, or Superspy. The other was the street kid, perhaps with a heart of gold but obviously on the path to becoming a Supervillain, who would get a structured environment, getting up at 0-dark-30, five mile run before breakfast, then the opportunity to repay his debt to society by using his powers in approved ways instead. Neither narrative was anything like Karen.
Karen was a cute little baby, then a cute little toddler, finally a nice teenager. Her father was a Highschool sports coach and Sunday School teacher. Her mother was a lawyer. Her aunt was TV news host. A perfect childhood.
Then Karen developed a superpower. This was noticed at her school, and Karen was 'drafted' into the government Supers project. She was unhappy there, developed depression. From monthly visit to monthly visit, her parents could watch her decline. They took pictures during their visits, recorded a video diary afterwards. On Christmas Eve of the second year of her draft, she jumped from her window. Someone took a picture of Karen's broken body in the snowed courtyard and smuggled it to her parents.
It wasn't supposed to be like this when the Supers Draft Law was passed. Karen was not the kind of Super people had in mind. Especially, Karen's family was not what people had in mind. Karen's family would not be silenced.
Three years later, "Karen's Law" was passed and the Supers Draft was rescinded.

A strong sense of individual liberty and the unforseen consequences of doing so
The first part is pretty simple - in the Anglosphere, we are generally pretty strong on individual rights and freedoms, the presumption  of innocence etc.
If they've done nothing wrong, then it would be immoral to capture him.
Also, something something slavery.
the next point is far more interesting
Consider how long a government would last if they did this:
"If they can do it to a superhero, they can do it to any of us" - Tyranny has a nasty habit of galvanizing the masses into action.
And the citizenry almost always win.

What would they need them for?
You hypothesize that they have the means to kidnap a powerful telekinetic and, presumably, keep him captive.  That means they have, effectively, power to nullify his abilities.
In a world where his abilities can be so easily nullified by those with power, they could be nullified by the people they wish to use this telekinetic against.
While there are non-hostile uses for his powers, it is unlikely that his powers are so incrementally greater than non-powered means of doing the same thing that keeping him prisoner forever is cheaper.

I would argue you can nullify any soldier with a simple prison. That does not make them less dangerous if embedded in a modern military. In addition, we have many technologies that 'nullify' other weapons. If we look at battlefields like Ukraine we see MRLS can nullify planes, and yet planes play an important role in the war. The ability to nullify has a lot of circumstance.

@Trioxidane If his telekinetic powers are not sufficient to let him out of prison -- breaking through walls, picking locks, stealing guns and threatening the guards -- they aren't so great as to make him so vital that you would put yourself to the effort and expense of kidnapping and keeping him prisoner.  This is why governments generally do not kidnap soldiers

To me it is saying a hacker is harmless in all situations, because you can take away their laptop if you lock them up. Maybe the telekinetic is kept perpetually on drugs, like an induced coma. Maybe they have their kid hostage. Maybe there's things in place that will prevent escape. Like if they damage the wall then water will automatically fill the room, which might be hard to control with telekinesis. There are many ways to (temporarily) nullify powers without affecting their overall capabilities. The powers can have great power only in specific circumstances that isn't escaping capture.

@Trioxidane All of those things would put extreme limits on what the telekinetic can do.  Induced coma in particular would simply obliterate their capabilities.

Is this a Frame Challenge?

@JBH No, because the question is not asking how such superhumans would be kidnapped.  It is asking what is the motive for people to not do it.

@Mary Per the [help/on-topic], If ... you aren’t sure what a character (be it an individual or organization) should do, that is out of scope for the site. and per [answer], Answer well-asked questions. If this isn't a frame challenge, then you shouldn't have answered the question.
